# Tizen Web API - writing simultaneous sensor data to a specific directory

Tags: java, tizen

I have just started to use Tizen Studio. I want to obtain the accelerometer sensor data of the smartwatch 4.0 and save it to a specific directory. Until now, I have managed to read the sensor data simultaneously. However, I need to collect all the data that I read to my hard drive, not the virtual root. I will be appreciated so much for any given idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

how about to use C# for your application?

Tizen supports C# dev environment with [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) + [Tizen Plugin](https://docs.tizen.org/application/vstools/install/).

Recommended sample apps: [Workout](https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen-CSharp-Samples/tree/master/Wearable/Workout), [SQLite.Net.Sample](https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen-CSharp-Samples/tree/master/Wearable/SQLite.NET.Sample)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. C# may help me to achieve my purposes. Cheers!